# Lenovo Laptop won't charge above 59%

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery

On my Lenovo laptop, running windows 7, I has got a prompt saying that, the system has noticed I am mainly using adapter, therefore I should keep the battery half charged. It justified the recommendation by saying that trying to overcharge battery reduces life time.

Occasionally I need to use my laptop on the go (that's why I bought a laptop)  but I can't for the life of me find and disable this program setting, so now I am stuck with 59% potential power at best.  Does anyone know how to change this setting?

I have tried the obvious i.e. search through Control Panel -> Power Settings but it seems I can't find how/where to disable this feature.

Comment: Now who would risk wasting your time!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have [Lenovo Power Manager](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-70601) already installed?  I'm presuming the message you got came from this.

Open the Lenovo Power Manager, click on the Battery tab, and then click the "Battery Maintenance" button.  This opens the Battery Maintenance window, where you should be able to adjust the charge mode settings -- including setting it to always fully charge.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Start, Type Power, you will get Power Management Options. Click on it, you will get a logo enabled with settings option. Click on Battery settings with Battery Symbol. Enable Full Battery Charging Mode, Applly, OK. Now you can see your Battery is charging :)

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo settings>click option>specific settings>power>conversation mode off

or

Lenovo settings>click battery icon and then choose which mode you want to use
(I suggest high performance mode)

Answer (score 0):

I know, I use a Lenovo too, and if you remove or bump the battery, the battery only gives an estimate instead of the actual percentage of the battery life, which makes for very bad charging.

The remedy takes maybe a weekend, when you're not using the laptop for a couple of days. Plug into an outlet where the computer will not be disturbed. Close out of all windows you have open. Open the Lenovo Power Manager and click on the Battery Tab. Click on the Battery Maintenance button, and a window will pop up. (If you can't find the Battery Maintenance button, you need to switch your view from Basic to Advanced by clicking the button in the upper right.) Click the Perform Reset button, and answer Continue to the prompt.

Then it just takes some time. Just leave it to sit for a day or so, and open it up again to check on the progress. If the Perform Reset button says Perform Reset again, the reset is done, and it should work better now.

Hope that helped!